# How to create a 1:1 Teams-Chat via Graph | Graph API | C#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working on a console app for my organization, that would take a list of email IDs and sends one-on-one chat message to them, from a certain email ID.

The sender & receivers - are all from the same organization.

To test this in my local machine, I have registered an app in Azure AD with my personal email (which is different from org email) and these are the permissions. All of these are `Application Permissions` only and I have not set any `Delegated Permissions`.

[image]

This is the code to create a chat.

```
private static async void CreateChat(string token)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);

            var chat = new Chat
            {
                ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
                Members = new ChatMembersCollectionPage()
                {
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$my_org_name@myorg.com')"}
                        }
                    },
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$receiver_org_name@myorg.com')"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var chatResult = graphClient.Chats
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(chat);

        }
```

I see this for the chatResult:

[image]

In order to test, should I register my app in Azure AD with my org email only.

I'm following [Example 3: Create a one-on-one chat using user principal name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Does `AddAsync` need to be awaited? Typically async methods would need that

Answer (score 1):

This is my Code and it works, but I use my Org-Account instead of my private.

```
///GetUser
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = this.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(scopes);

  try
  {
    var result = await graphServiceClient.Users[userEmail].Request().GetAsync();
    return result;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (raiseError == false)
      return null;
    else
      throw;

///Create Chat
  foreach (var curUser in userList)
    graphUsers.Add(curUser, base.GetUser(curUser, false, scopes));

  var chat = new Chat
  {
    ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
    Members = new ChatMembersCollectionPage()
    {
      new AadUserConversationMember
      {
        Roles = new List<string>()
        {
          "owner"
        },
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
          { "user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('" + userId + "')" }
        }
      },
      new AadUserConversationMember
      {
        Roles = new List<string>()
        {
          "owner"
        },
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
          { "user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('"+ userList[0] +"')" }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return graphClient.Chats.Request().AddAsync(chat);
```